Flutter Execution failed for task ':file_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

/Users/mycomputer/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_picker-8.1.5/android/src/main/java/com/mr/flutter/plugin/filepicker/FilePickerPlugin.java:257: error: cannot find symbol
    if (registrar != null) {
        ^
   symbol:   variable registrar
   location: class FilePickerPlugin
   /Users/mycomputer/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_picker-8.1.5/android/src/main/java/com/mr/flutter/plugin/filepicker/FilePickerPlugin.java:260: error: cannot find symbol
          registrar.addActivityResultListener(this.delegate);
          ^
  symbol:   variable registrar
  location: class FilePickerPlugin
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':file_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I'm getting the error with file_picker plugin. I have also deleted the .gradle file but it does not help. I have also changed the file_picker version but it does not help.

They just updated their plugin. Download the latest version of file_picker.

The latest update version 8.1.6 (see https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker/changelog#816) to file_picker fixed the issue via https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/pull/1644
The PR essentially removes a code section leftover for v1 embedding support. The ticket https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/1643 had a ton of duplicates (people don't check if it's already reported), and some PR errornously re-introduced imports for the v1 code section to sooth the compiler, instead of yanking them out. V1 embedding is gone for a good while now.
Temporary fix until this new version was to use the PR's branch:
  file_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/abdelaziz-mahdy/flutter_file_picker
      ref: fix-flutter-3.27-compile-error

(with or without a dependency_overrides, taste differs)
Apparently those v1 embedding codes were removed but another PR  accidentally merged only remnants of the v1 embedding code back. Tge issue is now fixed.

I was facing the same issue.
Go to pubspec.yaml
and change file picker to exact this version :
file_picker: 8.1.4


I have the same issue, updating file_picker version does not change anything, even with flutter clean && flutter pub get.

Upgrading to file_picker 8.1.6 resolved this issue for me.
